# Backup a derby database with excluding a table

Tags: java, derby, database-backups

I need to backup a derby database (both data and schema) to be restored later using Java

but I need exclude one of the tables that is very big in size, and it's not important in this case to be backed up

**Is there is any way to export a table as a create statement and list of inset statements?**

---

**I found the following ways to backup, but non of them work in my case:**

1. `SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE`

   This one will include the table that I don't want in include in the backup

   If I can exclude that table, that will be good.
2. `SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE`

   Calling it for each table is fine, but I don't know how to backup/restore the table schema on that point to restore!

   It generates a comma separated file with the data on that point of time.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of the `SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE` system procedure is the `SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE` procedure: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefimportproc.html

To make a full backup and restore solution out of this, I'd suggest:

1. Collecting all your export commands into a script and treat that script like a real program (put it under source control, test it, get it reviewed by your colleague, etc.)
2. Initially, don't try to restore right back into the same database. Create a new database, and restore the data into the new database. In particular, this will help with your testing because you can write commands to fetch the data out of both the old and the new databases and compare them.